# Schema error with Azure BizTalk Services EDI Bridge

Tags: azure, biztalk, edi, biztalk-services

I'm new to EDI and BizTalk, so some of our issues may be due to our inexperience, but hoping someone can help provide some guidance. Our ultimate goal is as follows:

> .NET send XML data -> Azure BizTalk EDI Bridge -> map XML data into X12 format -> Relay to AS2 Bridge -> which ultimately connects to our client's connection

Right now we are stuck on the step of mapping the XML data into X12 format. We are passing the data to the EDI Bridge, and based on the tracking messages, it appears it is reaching that correctly. We have made it past the agreement step, and the error we are getting is related to the schema.

Details of the error I'm seeing from the tracking messages:

> *Message cannot be serialized since the schema http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006#X12_00401_850 could not be located. Either the schema is not deployed or multiple copies are deployed.*
>
> *Activity: EDI Assembler Activity*
>
> *Stage: EDI Assembler Stage*

I have uploaded both the source and destination schemas to Azure. The target schema (X12_00401_850) is a schema I got from the Microsoft Templates provided with BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Developer tools (in case this source matters). In trying to troubleshoot this, I tried to set the target schema to a custom schema we created, and I received a different error -- that the output wasn't EDIfact or X12 (which makes sense).

Let me know if I need to provide more information or if anyone has any suggestions. Haven't had much luck finding the solution online, so hoping someone here can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific about hwo you "uploaded the source and destination schemas to Azure"?  Also, did you change the targetNamespace on the schema?

Comment: I tried uploading the schemas a few different ways. I tried uploading directly through the Azure BizTalk admin portal -- navigating to resources and uploading that way. I also tried uploading directly through visual studio (using the biztalk services explorer). In either scenario I had the same behavior. I did not change the target namespace on the schema. Can you elaborate on what may be needed on this? Maybe this is the step that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The schema needs to be added to the project you're deploying to MABS (it could be the same project as the map, but it's really best practice to separate schemas and maps into separate projects in BizTalk).  Add the schema to the project, build the project, and make sure it's getting deployed properly (without error) during your deployment process from Visual Studio.  This will take care of uploading the data to MABS - there is no other separate process that gets used to add the schema to MABS.

Comment: Tried this but still getting same error. I should mention that I am trying to call the EDI Bridge endpoint directly from my .NET application. I have a test XML bridge I created in visual studio, but in the end I'm not calling that from my .NET code -- my application is instead posting data directly to the EDI bridge. As I've mentioned I'm new to all this, so if this approach doesn't make sense let me know -- but wasn't sure how else to get data to pass from my custom .NET application into the EDI bridge. From the tracking messages I've seen, it appears this is reaching the bridge correctly.